# Inserting a combination of array and multidimensional array into MySQL table

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

There are two(2) scenarios when retrieving entries from the users.

- Scenario 1: User enters one(1) entry per person
- Scenario 2: User enters more than one(1) entry for either or both person(s)

**Scenario 1:**

User enters one(1) entry for each person.
[image]

var_dump() returns (correct)

```
array(
    5
)
    {
    [0] => string(8) "John Doe"1 => string(6) "Apples"2 => string(2) "50"[3] => string(3) "200"[4] => string(10) "2015-01-16"
    }

array(
    5
)
    {
    [0] => string(8) "Jane Doe"1 => string(7) "Bananas"2 => string(2) "20"[3] => string(3) "100"[4] => string(10) "2015-01-16"
    }
```

**Scenario 2:**

User enters more than one(1) entry for either or both person(s).
[image]

var_dump() returns (Incorrect)

```
array(
    5
)
    {
    [0] => string(8) "John Doe"1 => string(6) "Apples"2 => string(2) "50"[3] => string(3) "200"[4] => string(10) "2015-01-16"
    }

array(
    5
)
    {
    [0] => string(8) "Jane Doe"1 => string(7) "Oranges"2 => string(2) "20"[3] => string(3) "100"[4] => string(10) "2015-01-16"
    }

array(
    5
)
    {
    [0] => NULL1 => string(7) "Bananas"2 => string(2) "20"[3] => string(3) "200"[4] => string(10) "2015-01-16"
    }
```

The above dump shows the second entry with **Jane Doe** instead of **John Doe** and the entry for **Jane Doe** with a **NULL** name entry.

**HTML Form**

```
 <div class="toclone">

     <p class="name">
         <input type="text" name="name[]" id="sname" placeholder="Name"/> 
     </p> 
     <div class="inner-wrap">
         <!-- <strong>Procurement Information</strong> -->
         <div class="clone-inner">
             <p> 
                 <input type="text" name="item[]" id="sitem" placeholder="Item"/>
                 <input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="sqty" placeholder="Quantity"/> 
                 <input type="text" name="amount[]" id="samt" placeholder="Amount"/> 
                 <input type="text" name="date[]" id="sdate" placeholder="Date"/> 

                 <a href="#" class="phclone btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i></a>
                 <a href="#" class="phdelete btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i></a>
             </p>
         </div>
     </div>
     <a href="#" class="clone btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i> Add Name</a>
     <a href="#" class="delete btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i> Delete Name</a>
 </div>

 <p class="submit"> 
     <input type="submit" name="saveProcurement" value="Save" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"/> 
 </p>
```

**Controller**

```
 $name  = $this->input->post('name');

 $item  = $this->input->post('item');

 $quantity = $this->input->post('quantity');

 $amount    = $this->input->post('amount');

 $date     = $this->input->post('date');

 $limit = array(); 

 if (count($name) >= count($item)) {
     $limit = $name;
 } else {
     $limit = $item; 
 }

 for ($i = 0; $i < count($limit); $i++) {   
     var_dump(array($name[$i], $item[$i], $quantity[$i], $amount[$i], $date[$i]));                       
 }
```

How do I modify the loop to allow both scenarios to work fine?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would like to see the JSON POST data?

Comment: No JSON data. I'm capturing the form data and storing them in array (see controller code).

Comment: Ok I would like to see the form and the way the post data is converted into an array.

Comment: You cannot fetch the name and the items in the same loop you need to split it:

Comment: If I split them, I might have 2 records for names and 3/4 records for items etc. How will that work?

Comment: Just took a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="rows[]" id="srows" value="1" />
```

Every time a name is added or deleted this input should reflect the number of rows.

Your updated template:

```
<div class="toclone">

     <p class="name">
         <input type="text" name="name[]" id="sname" placeholder="Name"/> 
         <input type="hidden" name="rows[]" id="srows" value="1" /> 
     </p> 
     <div class="inner-wrap">
         <!-- <strong>Procurement Information</strong> -->
         <div class="clone-inner">
             <p> 
                 <input type="text" name="item[]" id="sitem" placeholder="Item"/>
                 <input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="sqty" placeholder="Quantity"/> 
                 <input type="text" name="amount[]" id="samt" placeholder="Amount"/> 
                 <input type="text" name="date[]" id="sdate" placeholder="Date"/> 

                 <a href="#" class="phclone btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i></a>
                 <a href="#" class="phdelete btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i></a>
             </p>
         </div>
     </div>
     <a href="#" class="clone btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i> Add Name</a>
     <a href="#" class="delete btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i> Delete Name</a>
 </div>

 <p class="submit"> 
     <input type="submit" name="saveProcurement" value="Save" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"/> 
 </p>
```

The updated controller.php:

```
$name  = $_POST['name'];

 $item  = $_POST['item'];

 $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

 $amount    = $_POST['amount'];

 $date     = $_POST['date'];

 $limit = array(); 

 if (count($name) >= count($item)) {
     $limit = $name;
 } else {
     $limit = $item; 
 }

 $offset = 0;
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['name']); $i++) {  

     for ($j = 0; $j < intval($_POST['rows'][$i]); $j++)
     {
          $dataArray = array($name[$i]);
          array_push($dataArray, $item[$offset + $j], $quantity[$offset + $j], $amount[$offset + $j], $date[$offset + $j]);
          var_dump($dataArray);
     }
     $offset = intval($_POST['rows'][$i]);

 }
```

Tested this on my machine with your input:

```
 array(5) { [0]=> string(6) "Mouser" [1]=> string(4) "test" [2]=> string(2) "20" [3]=> string(2) "30" [4]=> string(4) "3000" } 
 array(5) { [0]=> string(6) "Mouser" [1]=> string(5) "test2" [2]=> string(2) "20" [3]=> string(2) "40" [4]=> string(4) "4000" } 
 array(5) { [0]=> string(7) "Mouser2" [1]=> string(5) "test3" [2]=> string(2) "39" [3]=> string(3) "489" [4]=> string(5) "34499" }
```

The first loop runs through all names. The the inner loop cycles through all the data. The row index provided by the hidden input sets the offset for the data. So the offset for `John Doe` is `0 + n` where `n` is the amount of rows (2). For `Jane` it's `2 + n` where `n` is one row.

I'm not using codeIngniter so I've changed the retrieval of the POST vars to php's native `$_POST`.

Comment: After editing your code. it returns names. How do I relate the names with the item entries?

Comment: @h4kl0rd How do you mean names?

Comment: var_dump($dataArray) returns names only. It doesn't enter the second loop, so array_push() isn't executed. `array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "Company 1" } array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "Company 2" }`

Comment: My for lus had a bug in it. Could you try again?

Comment: Yes I fixed it and then ran the code. And the above output is what I get.

Comment: Could you sniff out what `intval($this->input->post('rows')[$i]` is giving back?

Comment: @h4kl0rd It's working as I should now on my machine.

Comment: intval($this->input->post('rows')[$i]) returns `int(0) int(0)`

Comment: @h4kl0rd The solution provided in my answer works. You only need to add logic to the `add name` and `delete name` function to reflect the amount of name rows per instance within the hidden input.

Comment: when I var_dump() name, items, quantity, amount and date they show, but rows returns bool(false)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69071/discussion-between-h4kl0rd-and-mouser).